# .htaccess Rewrite Domain & Preserve Path

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone assist me with rewriting a domain name but preserving the path?  I cannot seem to find what I am looking for, found a lot of articles about redirecting, but not rewriting.

```
www.domain2.com/path1/page.html as www.domain1.com/path1/page.html
www.domain2.com/path1/page.html as www.domain1.com/path1/page.html
```

I have quite a lot of domain names.

Many thanks for your advice or link to an article with the answer.

Stu

Comment: Actually if you could explain the redirect vs the rewrite that might be quite good to know.  Also can you rewrite non ssl as ssl?

Comment: Are all the domain names pointing to the same server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect One domain to another on the same IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830898/redirect-one-domain-to-another-on-the-same-ip)

Comment: Yeah same server multi-store magento installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `.htaccess`code will do it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For the difference between Rewriting and Redirecting it is very small. The first one is a location redirection which is not explicit (the user will not see it in his/her browser address bar) the second is a full redirection.

To rewrite non SSL as SSL change the url prefix from `http` to `https` and make sure you have a valid SSL certificate.